# Python+Selenium, can't click the 'button' wrapped by span

Tags: python, selenium, onclick, css-selectors, webdriver

I am new to selenium here. I am trying to use selenium to click a 'more' button to expand the review section everytime after refreshing the page.

The website is TripAdvisor. The logic of `more` button is, as long as you click on the first `more` button, it will automatically expand all the review sections for you. In other words, you just need to click on the first 'more' button.

All buttons have a similar class name. An example is like `taLnk.hvrIE6.tr415411081.moreLink.ulBlueLinks`. Only the numbers part changes everytime.

The full element look like this:

```
<span class="taLnk hvrIE6 tr413756996 moreLink ulBlueLinks" onclick="          var options = {
      flow: 'CORE_COMBINED',
      pid: 39415,
      onSuccess: function() { ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(2247); ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.expandReviews', {type: 'dummy'}, ta.id('review_413756996'), 'review_413756996', '1', 2247);; window.location.hash = 'review_413756996'; }
    };
    ta.call('ta.registration.RegOverlay.show', {type: 'dummy'}, ta.id('review_413756996'), options);
    return false;
  ">
More&nbsp; </span>
```

I have tried several ways to get the button click. But since it is an onclick event wrapped by span, I can't successfully get it clicked.

My last version looks like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(newurl)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
moreID = soup.find("span", class_=re.compile(r'.*\bmoreLink\b.*'))['class']
moreID = '.'.join(moreID[0:(len(moreID)+1)])
moreButton = 'span.' + moreID
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(moreButton)
button.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

However, I keep getting the error message like this:

> WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (318.5,
>   7.100006103515625). Other element would receive the click....

Can you advise me on how to fix the problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Also, I tried the wait function - {WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, more)))} and got an empty error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (318.5, 7.100006103515625). Other element would receive the click....

This error to be occur when element is not in the view port and selenium couldn't click due to some other overlay element on it. In this case you should try one of these following solution :-

- You can try using `ActionChains` to reach that element before click as below :-

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(moreButton)

  ActionChains(button).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
  ```
- You can try using `execute_script()` to reach that element before click as :-

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", button)
  button.click()
  ```
- You can try  using `JavaScript::click()` with `execute_script()` but this `JavaScript::click()` defeats the purpose of the test. First because it doesn't generate all the events like a real click (focus, blur, mousedown, mouseup...) and second because it doesn't guarantee that a real user can interact with the element. But to get rid from this issues you can consider it as an alternate solution.

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)
  ```

**Note**:- Before using these options make sure you're trying to interact with correct element using with correct locator, otherwise `WebElement.click()` would work well after wait until element visible and clickable using `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: Thanks! driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button) works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
# Your existing code here
# Minus the `button.click()` line
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).cli‌​ck().perform()
```

I have used this technique when I need to click on a `<div>` or a `<span>` element, rather than an actual button or link.

Comment: Thank you elethan. I tried. But I still get the same error message as the one in my question.

Comment: @backpackerice did you make sure to get rid of your original call to `button.click()`?

Comment: @ elethan. Yes, I did. I was wondering if this is because there is another span nearby that has exactly the same size, same class name, same onlick value, same everything. So when I try to click on coordinates of this span, the other button stopped it. To make it clear, there are two types of 'more' buttons. One to expand the review content, the other to expand the respond content. I only need to click on the first 'more' button on that page. No matter which one it is. I thought find.element (w/o s) will help me to find the first one. But it didn't.

Comment: @backpackerice you might try one of the `find_elements_by...` methods instead of the `find_element_by...` methods. These methods will return a list of elements, and you might be able to get the right element from that list. For example, in your case: `buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(moreButton)` would give you a list of elements with a css selector matching `moreButton`. Do you know for sure which element on the page `button` is currently pointing to?

Comment: Thanks. I used the ActionChains and was able to make it successfully run once. However, it failed for the next run. Probably because the connection issue. But thank you!